# Strange output when converting string to double

Tags: c#, string, double

I already searched for my problem but I wasn't successfully and that's the reason I'm here.

All I want to do is reading a string like "3.14" and convert it to double.
Enough said... here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace GlazerCalcApplication
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string heightString;
            double height;

            heightString = Console.ReadLine();
            height = Convert.ToDouble(heightString);
            Console.WriteLine(height);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3.14
314

Press any key to continue...
```

Why is my double value not 3.14?

Instead of `Convert.ToDouble()` I also tried it with `double.Parse()` but I received the same behaviour. Reading strings like 3,14 is no problem.
Maybe I should also mention that I use MonoDevelop and a linux OS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: finally I found it out de-DE :D

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying the culture as Invariant:

```
height = Convert.ToDouble(heightString,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It seems the *decimal seperator* of your culture is *comma* instead of *dot* therefore *dot* is truncated after conversion.

Answer (score 3):

[`Convert.ToDouble(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses `Double.Parse(string, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` method explicitly.

Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#d98fcd7819f63d0f);

```
public static double ToDouble(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

It is likely your `CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `.` (dot). That's why you can't parse a string with `.` as a date seperator.

Example in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/);

```
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.Dump(); // Prints ,
```

As a solution, you can create a new reference of your `CurrentCulture` and assing it's [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `.` like;

```
double height;
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
height = Convert.ToDouble("3.14", c);
```

Comment: The `.Dump()` method is some custom extension method of yours or a part of the standard library?

Comment: Okay thanks for this information. As I'm coming from C I would never think of using a ',' as separator.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the result I take it you are in a culture zone where comma is the normal decimal separator.
Also, I take it that you want ***both*** dot and comma to be used for decimal separation.
If not, the below is not the proper solution.

The fastest solution for using both would be

```
height = Convert.ToDouble(heightString.Replace('.', ',');
```

This would mean that both dots and comma's are used as comma and thus parsed as a decimal separator.

If you only want to use a dot as separator, you can use *invariantculture* or a specific numberformatinfo. Invariant culture is already shown in the other posts. numberformat info example:

```
    var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
    height = double.Parse(heightString,nfi);
```

For completeness, the example below shows both using numberformatinfo for setting the dot as decimal separator, as well as replacing comma with dots, so both characters are used for decimals

```
    var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
    height = double.Parse(heightString.Replace(',', '.'),nfi);
```

Comment: +0: while most of the question have good details, I can't agree with replacing separators with `,`: "1.500" is not the same as "one and a half" for many countries...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The answer was based on that 3,14 worked, and manual input is used. Living in the Netherlands, we often want precisely that: both characters to be used as decimal separator, because our official separator is the comma, but input is often done with the dot (numeric keypad)

Comment: But you did not specify culture if you wanted `,` to be parsed always as decimal separator... I know couple people that don't live in Netherlands :)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True, I'm not sure of the Orpo's intent. Altered the post to indicate what I expected what he was after. However I must say that for manual input I've done exactly that a few times. Simply because the manually entered amounts never contained group separators, only decimal separators, but yes, that's specifying a specific group of users and the request specifically was that both were considered as decimal separators. (Wow, don't think I've ever written the word separator this much one place :D )

Answer (score 1):

Different .Net cultures (countries) have different decimal separators.

If you expect input values to be in some specific format - either use some particular culture or `InvariantCulture`. Also consider using [double.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it geve more flexibility on parsing the values than generic `Convert.ToDouble`.

```
    var d = double.Parse(heightString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you expect user to enter value in local format - your code is fine, but either your expectation of "local format" is wrong, or "current culture" set incorrectly.